# Creating Meshes from Pointclouds of Urban Scenes

Tags: ros, mesh, cgal, point-clouds

I want to create high fidelity meshes of urban street scenes using pointcloud data. The data consists of pointclouds using a HDL64-e and the scenes are very similar to the one in the [Kitti Dataset](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/raw_data.php).

Currently im only able to use the 'raw' point clouds and odometry of the car. Previous works already implemented the LeGO-LOAM algorithm to create a monolithic map and better odometry estimates.

**Available Data**:

- Point Clouds with 10Hz timings
- Odometry estimates with higher frequencies (LOAM Output)
- Monolithic map of the scene (LOAM Output) (~1.500.000 Points)

I already did some research and came to the conclusion, that I can either

- use the monolithic map with algorithms like Poisson Reconstruction, Advancing Front, etc... (using [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/))
- go the robotics way and use some packages like [Voxgraph](https://github.com/ethz-asl/voxgraph) (which uses Marching Cubes internally)

As we might want to integrate image data at a later step the second option would be preferred.

**Questions:**

- Is there a State-of-the-Art way to go?
- Is it possible to get a mesh that can preserve small features like curbs and sign posts? (I know there might be a feasable limit on how fine the mesh can be)

I am very interested in some feedback and a discourse on how to tackle this problem 'the right way'.

Thank you for your suggestions/answers in advance!